# Accessing ids in different classes in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to access a TextInput id and show it in another screen using Kivy but I'm unable to do so. I've tried everything I know, and because I'm rather new to Python and Kivy, I don't know what to look for. So if anyone could help me solve this problem, I'd really appreciate that.

1. Enter distance (eg. 50)
2. Second window displays the entered distance (eg. Distance: 50)

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

class DistWindow(Screen):
    get_dist = ObjectProperty(None)

    def distBtn(self):
        sm.current = "disp"

class DispWindow(Screen):
    show_dist = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.show_dist.text = "Distance: "  + str(DistWindow().get_dist.text)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [DistWindow(name = "dist"), DispWindow(name = "disp")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "dist"

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv:

```
<DistWindow>:
    name: "dist"
    get_dist: get_dist

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Max distance"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top": 0.9}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4

        TextInput:
            id: get_dist
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.7}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1

        Button:
            text: "Search"
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.1}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            on_release:
                root.distBtn()
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<DispWindow>:
    name: "disp"
    show_dist: show_dist

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            id: show_dist
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top": 0.9}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.2

        Button:
            text: "Go back"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "y": 0.1}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "dist"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code will work if you just change your `on_enter()` method of `DispWindow` class to:

```
def on_enter(self):
    self.show_dist.text = "Distance: " + self.manager.get_screen("dist").get_dist.text
```

In your original code, the

```
DistWindow().get_dist.text
```

is creating a new instance of `DistWindow` (unrelated to the one in your GUI), and taking the text from that.